# wxPython Message Dialog error "window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST"

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

My code

```
 def myCaller(self, event):


    wx.CallAfter(self.msgbox(0.3434, 0.34, 0.121))



 def msgbox(self, val, f1, f2):

    message = "Node Failure Probability: %f \nLeft Child Value: %f \nRight Child Value: %f" % (val, f1, f2)

    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, message, "Node Information", wx.OK)
    dlg.showmodal()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

The output comes out alright, but then I get an error in the Shell:

```
     dlg.ShowModal()
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows.py", line 711, in ShowModal
return _windows_.Dialog_ShowModal(*args, **kwargs)
    wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxAssertFailure" failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(2571) in DoNotifyWindowAboutCaptureLost(): window that captured the mouse didn't process wxEVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the code in you show but in the code calling it or, rather, in the moment chosen to call it. It's hard to be sure without knowing where do you call it from, but you must be doing it from some event handler invoked while the mouse is captured. Showing the message dialog breaks the mouse capture and results in the warning you're seeing.

There are two solutions: either modify the component that is capturing the mouse to react to capture failure or not show `wx.MessageDialog` at this time. The former risks to be difficult to do for you if it's something at C++ rather than Python level (although you could always try updating to wxPython 2.9.4 and see if the problem wasn't fixed in the meanwhile) but the latter can be easily done by just using [wx.CallAfter](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter).

Comment: I am calling the message box from a function bound to a button. I hav I have mad a change and included wx.CallAfter. Is it the right way ?

Comment: I dont think it will work 'cause I have 2.8. Will there be any issues if I update to 2.9.4?

Comment: As the button captures the mouse when it's clicked, this is one of the most frequent examples when you should indeed avoid showing a message box immediately. And yes, `wx.CallAfter` is the right thing to do and it should work in 2.8.

Comment: VZ, it was working fine for some time, now the problem is back again. You have mentioned something about not showing the message box immediately. Is there any alternative to CallAfter?. Thanks!